# memory assert when delete SkCanvas object

Tags: c++, memory, visual-c++, skia

When I use "delete mCanvas" to delete a SkCanvas object, debug with VS2022,  I get a memory assert "A breakpoint instruction was executed".

From the stack,  "skia.dll!SkCanvas::`vector deleting destructor`(unsigned int)" is being called.  Why does this happen? How should we delete SkCanvas object?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you probably need to give more context about your code for people to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to build skia with extra_cflags=["/MDd"] when in debug mode. This solved my issue.